# preload next iframe while current one is displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I am working in ASP.net and I have two urls that I am using to display as "SlideShow" using timer and iframes.  It works fine but, I want to make it so that next page is already loaded while the current page is displaying.Then, when timer clicks, the next page displays without any loading time. So, that user doesnt see any delay between the two page.

Can somebody help me how I can achive this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add 1 or more hidden iFrames to the dom with jQuery and add an attribute src="[url-to-load]".

```
var $frame = $('<iframe />');
$frame.css('display', 'none')
      .attr('src', '[url-to-load]');

$(document.body).append($frame);
```

You would need to write the carrousel functionality yourself then